# Как пишется выражение "Урок мужества"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, фразеология

Как пишется выражение "Урок мужества"?

Comment: Выражение — с прописной. Как — тоже.

Comment: Безобразный пережиток мужского шовинизма. Запретить.

Answer (score 5):

**Что выбираем?**

А выбираем мы  **прописную/строчную букву  и наличие/ отсутствие кавычек**, причем в обоих словах. Удивительно, но количество вариантов при сочетании этих четырех элементов оказалось значительным.

**Давайте вспомним правила.**

**Прописная буква** пишется,  если слово или словосочетание является именем собственным, нарицательные сочетания пишутся **со строчной буквы**.

**Прописная букв**а  может придавать словам особо важное (высокое) значение.

**В кавычки** может заключаться:  а) имя собственное, в том числе при наличии родового слова: б) нарицательное сочетание с условным значением; в) слова, имеющие иронический смысл.

**Выбираем  возможные варианты**

**1. Нарицательное сочетание *урок мужества*, в том числе в кавычках**

Этот вариант вполне приемлем в качестве термина  в образовательных учреждениях или в текстах на образовательные темы, когда значение выражения всем понятно.

Постановка кавычек факультативна и зависит от текста. Например,  кавычки нужны в том случае, если перед сочетанием есть определение (данный "урок мужества").

**Примеры:**  Проведение  **уроков мужества**  – директива Минобрнауки,  оно же разработало учебный материал.  3 сентября в школах прошли  **уроки мужества**, посвящённые 75-летию победы в Курской битве.

Пояснительная записка. Методика организации проведения **«уроков мужества».**

**2. Нарицательное сочетание *урок мужества* в качестве приложения для названия темы**

**Урок мужества** «Памяти павших будьте достойны!».  **Урок мужества**: « Эхо афганской войны» (Музыкально – литературная композиция).

**3. Имя собственное *Урок мужества*, в том числе при наличии родового слова**

В этом случае кавычки ставятся при наличии родового слова (презентация, классный час), а при его отсутствии могут не ставиться

Примеры:

Презентация  **«Урок мужества»**. "Найди себе идеал  мужества и постоянно следуй ему". (В. А. Сухомлинский).

Классный час  **«Урок мужества»**.

Проведение **«Уроков мужества»** (далее – **Уроки**) в образовательных организация необходимо осуществлять по следующему алгоритму

**4. Слово *мужество* пишем со строчной буквы и без кавычек**

Вариант  ***Уроки Мужества***, где обозначен высокий смысл слова,   нежелателен,  так как  в этом случае  оно вряд ли  нуждается в дополнительной коннотации. И тем более его не следует заключать в кавычки.

Вариант  ***урок Мужества***, где урок – приложение, а Мужества – имя собственное  **применяется**,  но не часто (он не кажется удачным).

Любовь к Родине в школьниках воспитывают с начальных классов, ежегодно проводя **уроки Мужества**. Данный  **урок Мужества**  посвящён теме «Никто не забыт, ничто не забыто».  Ежегодно в преддверие празднования Дня Победы в школах проводят **Уроки Мужества.**